# Can be Neo4j Spatial data exposed to GeoServer via the Neo4j Geoserver Plugin being edited via WFS-T protocol?

Tags: geoserver, java, wfs-t, neo4j

I'd like to set up some data storage as Neo4j as I need the advantages of graph databases for may data, but I'm not sure that the data would be spatially editable via WFS-T and Geoserver. Does Neo4j Geoserver plugin just allows showing the data, or it make possible the spatial edit too?

Is that is not the case, that is the technologies stack you could recommend to enable the spatial data change for the Neo4j spatial database?